# Parse command argument separated by comma

Tags: macros, parsing

I want to mix several language in my document, and the output language can be chosen according to corresponding variable

I want to define this kind of command
`\mulan[en,fr,ru]{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}`

to return

`\en{arg1}`  /  `\fr{arg2}`  / `\ru{arg3}`

The following is my basic frame, but I don't know how I can proceed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}


\newif\ifen % if English
\newif\iffr % if French
\newif\ifru % if Russia
\newif\ifcn % if Chinese
\newif\ifjp % if Japanese



\newcommand{\en}[1]{\ifen#1\fi}
\newcommand{\fr}[1]{\ifen#1\fi}
\newcommand{\ru}[1]{\ifru#1\fi}
\newcommand{\cn}[1]{\ifcn#1\fi}
\newcommand{\jp}[1]{\ifjp#1\fi}

%specify the multi languge sequence variable globaly
\def\mulanseq#1{\gdef\mymulanseq{#1}}
\newcommand{\mymulanseq}[2]{#1 #2}

\newcommand{\mulan}[2][]{
    \mymulan{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{\mymulanseq}{#1}}{#2}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mymulanp}[2]
{

 (#1): #2  
 
}


\begin{document}

%choose output language
\entrue
\jptrue
\cnfalse

%define default language sequence
\mulanseq{en,jp,cn}

%explain the three sententces according default language sequence
\mulan{en-sentence}{jp-sentence}{cn-sentence}

%explain the three sententces according given language sequence
\mulan[cn,jp,en]{sentence-A}{sentence-B}{sentence-C}

%deal with variable number sentence
% only 1 sentence should be explained using the first language specification
\mulan{sentence-A}

% only 1 sentence should be explained using the first language specification
\mulan{sentence-A}{sentence-B}


\end{document}
```

---

Big thanks to Steven.  Perfectly solved my question.

Can I requrie more than this?

To make the command `\mulan[en,ru,fr,...]{s1}{s2}{s3}` more practical,
another seperating args `\mysep` is wanted.

```
\mulan[en,ru,fr,...]{\mysep}{s1}{s2}{s3}
```

For example, concerning the following commands

```
\mulan[en,ru,fr]{\mysep}{s1}{s2}{s3}
```

will output

```
 s1 \mysep s2 \mysep s3
```

(note: at the end of the `s3`, there is no `\mysep`)

When one of the languages is turned off, the corresponding seperator does not occur either.

```
\entrue
\rufalse
\frtrue
\mulan[en,ru,fr]{\mysep}{s1}{s2}{s3}
```

will output

```
 s1 \mysep s3
```

and if the commands

```
\entrue
\rutrue
\frfalse
\mulan[en,ru,fr]{\mysep}{s1}{s2}{s3}
```

will give output

```
s1 \mysep s2
```

---

2015/02/10

Thanks a lot, .Steven.

I think the command you defined, `\mulan` should have the following full format:

```
\mulan[en,jp,cn]{seperator}{Language-1}{Language-2}{Language-3}
```

For more convience in practical use, I want to define several simplified version for the `\mulan`

For example,

1. if the language sequence is not given, the command `\mulan` will use default language sequence given by a global variable, such as `\mulanseq`

   ```
   \mulanseq{jp,cn,en}
   \mulan{+++}{MyJapanese}{MyChinese}{MyEnglish}
   ```
2. I want to define an alias command `\mulanp` for `\mulan`, which will give some paragrah sepeprated for different language contents. Just like:

   ```
   \newcommand\mulanp#1{\mulan{\par}{#1}}
   \newcommand\mulanr#1{\mulan{\space/\space}{#1}}
   ```

So that I can input less duplicate contents in my main text.
Also, if the language sequence is not specified in `\mulanp`, the default sequence will be used.

Though I am learning programing in LaTeX and I am trying to read and modify your program for dedicated uses, it is far for me to understand thoroughly your program soon.

Would you like to give me more help?

Note: for the above question 2, I have realized by the following

```
\def\mulanp{\expandafter\mulan{\par}}
\mulanp{MyJapanese}{MyChinese}{MyEnglish}
```

It looks o.k. but the first question needs your genius yet.

Comment: Generally, once an original question is adequately answered, it is preferable to ask follow ups as a new, separate question (while referring to the original question).  That way, you will likely get new sets of eyes upon the new question.  If a question is answered adequately, the protocol is to click the big check mark next to that answer.  That generally signifies that a question is complete.

Comment: However, I will give thought to your follow up...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solve the 2nd question by define a new command . The first question is not solved yet.
    \def\mulanp{\expandafter\mulan{\par}}
    \mulanp{MyJapanese}{MyChinese}{MyEnglish}

Comment: Don't change your question so that it invalidates the already given answers. Please, open a new question stating ***precisely*** the specifications.

Comment: See also [macros - Command with arguments separated by comma - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453007/command-with-arguments-separated-by-comma)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took some time to figure out how to do it without knowing the number of arguments in advance.  The key was to have `\mulan` insert a dummy argument, in this case `relax`, at the end of the list, which got transformed by `\langcmd` to `\relax`, and was used to shut down the process.

And, as it turned out, I didn't need any packages.  EDITED to add default language sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{args}
\newcommand\mulan[1][en,jp,cn]{%
  \setcounter{args}{0}%
  \commaparse#1,\relax%
  \stepcounter{args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname{relax}
  \setcounter{args}{0}%
  \langcmd%
}
\def\commaparse#1,#2\relax{%
  \stepcounter{args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname{#1}%
  \if\relax#2\else\commaparse#2\relax\fi%
}
\newcommand\langcmd{%
  \stepcounter{args}%
    \csname\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname\endcsname%
}
\def\en#1{Run en on #1!\langcmd}
\def\fr#1{Run fr on #1!\langcmd}
\def\ru#1{Run ru on #1!\langcmd}
\def\jp#1{Run jp on #1!\langcmd}
\def\cn#1{Run cn on #1!\langcmd}
\begin{document}
\mulan[en,fr,ru]{arg1}{arg2}{arg3} Following text\par
\mulan[fr,jp]{arg1}{arg2} Next\par
\mulan[en]{arg1} and so on\par
\mulan[en,fr,ru,jp]{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4} ...\par
%explain the three sententces according default languajp sequence
\mulan{en-sentence}{jp-sentence}{cn-sentence}\par
\mulan[cn,jp,en]{sentence-A}{sentence-B}{sentence-C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

Here I hit the points of the OP's follow up with this modified solution:

1. I take an additional mandatory 1st argument which is the separator between answers (but not before the first nor after the last).
2. I have EDITED to handle if-conditionals to turn off languages;
3. **Much later REEDIT to allow the default sequence to placed in a `\def`, rather than be explicitly specified.  It required the addition of `\expandafter` before the invocation of `\commaparse` in the definition of `\mulan`.**

Here is the revised MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{args}
\def\defaultsequence{en,jp,cn}
\newcommand\mulan[2][\defaultsequence]{%
  \gdef\thesep{#2}%
  \setcounter{args}{0}%
  \expandafter\commaparse#1,\relax%
  \stepcounter{args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname{relax}%
  \setcounter{args}{0}%
  \langcmd%
}
\def\commaparse#1,#2\relax{%
  \stepcounter{args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname{#1}%
  \if\relax#2\else\commaparse#2\relax\fi%
}
\newcommand\langcmd{%
  \stepcounter{args}%
  \csname\csname arg\romannumeral\value{args}\endcsname\endcsname%
}
\newcommand\callsep{\ifnum\value{args}>1\thesep\fi}

\newif\ifen \newif\iffr \newif\ifru \newif\ifjp \newif\ifcn
\def\en#1{\ifen\callsep Run \textbf{en} on ``#1''!\fi\langcmd}
\def\fr#1{\iffr\callsep Run \textbf{fr} on ``#1''!\fi\langcmd}
\def\ru#1{\ifru\callsep Run \textbf{ru} on ``#1''!\fi\langcmd}
\def\jp#1{\ifjp\callsep Run \textbf{jp} on ``#1''!\fi\langcmd}
\def\cn#1{\ifcn\callsep Run \textbf{cn} on ``#1''!\fi\langcmd}
\parskip 1em\relax
\parindent 0pt\relax
\begin{document}
\entrue\frtrue\rufalse\jptrue\cntrue
\mulan[en,fr,ru,cn]{---}{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}\par
\rutrue
\mulan[en,fr,ru,cn]{---}{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}\par
BEFORE \mulan{\\}{en-sentence}{jp-sentence}{cn-sentence} NEXT!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are really a talent! I appreciate you so much. You help me a lot. I  hope one day I can become so strong as you.

Comment: @JilongYin Thank you for the kind words.  Best wishes to you and your family, proudly displayed in your icon.

Comment: I want to make your \mulang　command more practical by adding another \mysep argument for it. Could you please take a look at the end of my original question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JilongYin I have updated my answer to provide the separator;  However, I have not addressed the if-conditions you mention.

Comment: @JilongYin I have edited my update to provide both a separator s well as the if conditionals to turn off languages.

Comment: I try to add the if-conditions in your program(showed in the end of my original question, but it looks like the output is not exactly I want. Could you kindly please check it for me? Sorry to take you so much time.

Comment: @JilongYin I moved the `\ifnum` checks out of `\langcmd` macro and placed it in `\callsep`, which is called *after* the `\ifru` style conditions.  This avoids having the separator print when the condition is false.  See my update.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your coment after you add if-condtions. It looks like it works exactly correct. Pls admit me to use your program in my document.

Comment: @JilongYin with my blessing.

Comment: Would you like to strengthen  your \mulan command by permitting a default language sequence like \mulanseq{en,jp,cn}  \mlan{---}{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}  . Even a new command name is also OK. In this way, the input in main text can be simplified a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JilongYin It is already set up for the default language sequence `[en,jp,cn]`, which you can see as the default argument to my implementation of `\mulan`.

Comment: Thank you. Steven. I have noticed that. Actually, I want to put your \mulan command into a seperate .sty file. I don't want to edit that each time. Also, in my big document, in some paragraphs, e.g., they are mainly in English,Japanese, Chinese. But in some other paragrahs, they are mainly in Other languages. I want to a command to modify the language sequence conviently.

Comment: @JilongYin  That is easy.  Just `\def\defaultsequence{en,jp,cn}` in the preamble and define `\newcommand\mulan[2][\defaultsequence]{...}`.  Then, when you wish, you can redefine `\defaultsequence`, for example, `\def\defaultsequence{ru,jp,cn}`.

Comment: It seems that it does not work well when the seperator is \\ (or new paragrah). Could you check it.

Comment: @JilongYin I'm sorry, but it seems to work for me.  You will ntice the last example in my MWE has ``\\`` as the separator and that works.  If I replace the ``\\`` with `\par`, it also works.

Comment: I mean if you define \defaultsequence in preamble and replace the [en,jp,cn] with it in the \mulan defintion . It can not work fine when the seperator is \\.

Comment: @JilongYin  You can do what you suggest **if** you change the `\commaparse#1,\relax%` line in the `\mulan` definition to `\expandafter\commaparse#1,\relax%`.

Comment: @JilongYin Please see FOLLOW UP in revised answer.  I have made this part of the revised code.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try with a different syntax, where the arguments are tied to the language keys:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mulan}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { yin/mulan } { #1 }
  \seq_use:NV \l_yin_mulan_args_seq \l_yin_mulan_sep_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\enablelan}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \bool_set_true:c { l_yin_mulan_##1_bool }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\disablelan}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \bool_set_false:c { l_yin_mulan_##1_bool }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\seq_new:N \l_yin_mulan_args_seq
\bool_new:N \l_yin_mulan_en_bool
\bool_new:N \l_yin_mulan_fr_bool
\bool_new:N \l_yin_mulan_ru_bool
\bool_new:N \l_yin_mulan_cn_bool
\bool_new:N \l_yin_mulan_jp_bool

\keys_define:nn { yin/mulan }
 {
  sep .tl_set:N = \l_yin_mulan_sep_tl,
  sep .initial:n = { --- },
  en .code:n = \__mulan_append_lang:nn { en } { #1 },
  fr .code:n = \__mulan_append_lang:nn { fr } { #1 },
  ru .code:n = \__mulan_append_lang:nn { ru } { #1 },
  cn .code:n = \__mulan_append_lang:nn { cn } { #1 },
  jp .code:n = \__mulan_append_lang:nn { jp } { #1 },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mulan_append_lang:nn #1 #2
 {
  \bool_if:cT { l_yin_mulan_#1_bool }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_yin_mulan_args_seq
     {
      \use:c { mulan#1 } { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mulanen}[1]{Run \textbf{en} on ``#1''!}
\newcommand{\mulanfr}[1]{Run \textbf{fr} on ``#1''!}
\newcommand{\mulanru}[1]{Run \textbf{ru} on ``#1''!}
\newcommand{\mulanjp}[1]{Run \textbf{jp} on ``#1''!}
\newcommand{\mulancn}[1]{Run \textbf{cn} on ``#1''!}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\enablelan{en,fr,jp,cn}

\mulan{
  en=arg1,
  fr=arg2,
  ru=arg3,
  cn=arg4,
}

\section{B}
\enablelan{ru}

\mulan{
  en=arg1,
  fr=arg2,
  ru=arg3,
  cn=arg4,
}

\section{C}
\disablelan{fr}

\mulan{
  en=arg1,
  fr=arg2,
  ru=arg3,
  cn=arg4,
}

\section{D}

BEFORE 
\mulan{
  sep=\\,
  en=en-sentence,
  jp=jp-sentence,
  cn=cn-sentence,
}
NEXT!

\end{document}
```

The phrases are printed (if the language is enabled) in the order they're specified in the argument. If a fixed language order is preferred, the macros can be (quite easily) modified to accomplish it.

You just need to provide sensible definitions for the `\mulan<lang>` macros. How to add language tags should be self-explaining.

Comment: Also thanks for your solution. It really works. But when the sentence given in different language becomes very long, the key-value assignment seems a little unclear in document. Maybe your solution is very good for simple single sentence.