# Aliasing a variable argument command into tabular environment

Tags: tables, macros, alias

I am making a multi-language document. With the big help of Mr. Steven B. Segletes, I am able to deal with several languages mixed document, which can only output in wanted one or several laguages.  See the thread [ [Parse command argument separated by comma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226440/parse-command-argument-separated-by-comma) ]

I also aliased `\mulan` to new commands such as `\mulanp` and `\mulanr` so that the `\mulan` command can be simplified when the text is seperated  by `\par` or '/'.

Now I want it can also works in table use.  I know I can not insert a multiline sentence in a tab cell.
 So I hope the contents explained by `\mulan` command can be treated as a sub-tabular. Just like the following,

```
\mulanTL{A}{B}{C}
```

will give output

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
  A \\
  B \\
  C\\
\end{tabular}
```

I don't know how to define it. I tried a lot bu failed.  The following is my minimal example.  Though I am not sure you can compile it correctly because it includes CJK characters.

```
%
% Command \mulan usage example
% Compiled by XeLatex
\documentclass{article}

% CJK character support
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont,CJKnumber]{xeCJK}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Table packages
\usepackage{longtable}     %long table across multi pages

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%CJK settings
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhrm}{SimSun} %Chinese
\setCJKfamilyfont{jarm}{NSimSun} %Japanese
\setCJKfamilyfont{korm}{Batang} %Korean
\newcommand\Chinese{\CJKfamily{zhrm}\CJKnospace}
\newcommand\Japanese{\CJKfamily{jarm}\CJKnospace}
\newcommand\Korean{\CJKfamily{korm}\CJKspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \mulan comand defintion to deal with multiple language
\newif\ifen %English
\newif\iffr %French
\newif\ifru %Russian
\newif\ifjp %Japanese
\newif\ifcn %Chinese
\newif\ifkr %Korean
%
\def\en#1{\ifen\callsep #1\fi\langcmd}
\def\fr#1{\iffr\callsep #1\fi\langcmd}
\def\ru#1{\ifru\callsep #1\fi\langcmd}
\def\jp#1{\ifjp\callsep {\Japanese #1}\fi\langcmd}
\def\cn#1{\ifcn\callsep {\Chinese #1}\fi\langcmd}
\def\kr#1{\ifkr\callsep {\Korean #1}\fi\langcmd}



%specify the multi languge sequence variable globaly
\def\mulanseq#1{\gdef\my@mulanseq{#1}}
%\gdef\my@mulanseq{en,jp,cn}

\newcounter{mulan@args}

%\newcommand\mulan[2][en,jp,cn]{%  
\newcommand\mulan[2][en,jp,cn]{%  
  \gdef\thesep{#2}% 
  \setcounter{mulan@args}{0}%
  \commaparse#1,\relax%
  \stepcounter{mulan@args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{mulan@args}\endcsname{relax}%
  \setcounter{mulan@args}{0}%
  \langcmd%
}

\def\commaparse#1,#2\relax{%
  \stepcounter{mulan@args}%
  \expandafter\def\csname arg\romannumeral\value{mulan@args}\endcsname{#1}%
  \if\relax#2\else\commaparse#2\relax\fi%
}

\newcommand\langcmd{%
  \stepcounter{mulan@args}%
  \csname\csname arg\romannumeral\value{mulan@args}\endcsname\endcsname%
}

\newcommand\callsep{\ifnum\value{mulan@args}>1\thesep\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Convient alias command for \mulan
\def\mulanp{\expandafter\mulan{\par}}
\def\mulanr{\expandafter\mulan{ \space {\textbf{/}}\space}}

% multiline in tab cell !!! problem yet !!!
%\newcommand{\mulanTL}{\begin{tabular}{l}\expandafter\mulan{\\} \end{tabular} }  
\newcommand{\mulanTL}{\expandafter\mulan{ \space {\textbf{/}}\space}}  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%%---------------------
\entrue \jptrue \cntrue

%%%---------This command has not been finished yet------
%\mulanseq{en,jp,cn}

\title{\mulanp{Multilingual Document}{多言語文書}{多语言文档}}
\author{\mulanr{Jerome}{竹本　松一}{竹本先生}}

\maketitle 

\tableofcontents

\abstract

\section{\mulanr{Title}{標題}{标题}}

\mulanp{This is the text.}{これは正文です。}{这是正文。}


\mulanr{This is an example of table.}{これは表の例}{这是一个表格的例子}

\mulanTL{Japanese traditional craft, it can be seen even nowadays}{日本の伝統的な芸術}{日本传统艺术}  

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\hline
 \mulanr{Item}{項目}{项目}　& Price(USD) & \mulanr{Repark}{注釈}{备注}\\
\hline
 \mulanr{Japanese Paper}{和紙}{日本纸}  & 15.0 & \mulanTL{Japanese traditional craft, it can be seen even nowadays}{日本の伝統的な芸術}{日本传统艺术}    \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

---

---

If the number of arguments is fixed to, e.g. 3.
I can make the command as follows,

```
\newcommand\mulanT[4][l]{
 \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \mulan{\\}{#2}{#3}{#4} 
 \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\mulanTL{\mulanT[l]}
\newcommand\mulanTC{\mulanT[c]}
\newcommand\mulanTR{\mulanT[r]}
```

Is there any means to deal with the case with variable number of arguments?
if it requires the editing of the definiton of command `\mulan`, that will also be O.K.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are the number of arguments to `\mulanTL` variable? Or will it always be 3?

Comment: The number of arguments to \mulan   varies.  It is better if you define \mulanTL with  a variable number aguments too. If it is impossible to define that, you can fixed it as  three.

Comment: Is there anybody help me more?

Comment: @Werner please see Jilong's comment above. Jilong, please use @-notation (as I've done here for Werner) to notify them of your reply to a comment.

Comment: If it is a variable number of arguments, what syntax do you want to use?  One needs some way to know that there are no more arguments to process.

Comment: Andrew, I am not clear about Latex's syntax. It seems Latex can scan the following  string until an unexpected character occurs such as % } etc .