# Command with arguments separated by comma II (typically an easy way to write matrices)

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

Since I am using 2 x 2 matrices very frequently, I would like to define a command which would work like this: `\matr{a, b, c, d}` would produce
`$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$`.

Of course, I know how to get this result using something like `\matr{a}{b}{c}{d}`, but the point is to have a "comma-separated list" of arguments. A solution using `\matr{a, b}{c, d}` could be interesting as well (especially its generalization to 3 x 3 matrices).

Most of the answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453007/command-with-arguments-separated-by-comma), [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303942/newcommand-with-comma-separated-argument-and-optional-arguments) or [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118) seem to rely on `xparse` package. But I am highly unused to the LaTeX3 syntax, so I have no clue on how to tackle with my problem.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I cannot use LaTeX? It does not render currently... :-(

Comment: We deliberately do not have MathJaX on the site: if you need to show TeX output, make an image and upload it

Comment: This function already exists from within Emacs for matrices of all sizes. As a bonus, you can do all kinds of calculations on the matrices, see my answer for more precision.

Comment: There is an analogue command in `mlist` package: https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mlist/mlist.pdf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am highly unused to the LaTeX3 syntax too, so I give you non-exp3 solution based only on TeX primitives. You need not any LaTeX package (and you basically don't even need LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\matr#1{\def\matrL{}\matrA#1\end}
\def\matrA#1{\ifx\end#1\pmatrix{\matrL}\else 
   \ifx,#1\addto\matrL{&}\else
   \ifx;#1\addto\matrL{\cr}\else
   \addto\matrL{#1}\fi\fi
   \expandafter\matrA\fi
}

\begin{document}

$$
  \matr{a,b;c,d}\ne\matr{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12}
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! I think that I will accept this answer since it seems to be the only one that works with the (old) TexLive 2018, and also I feel that I would be able to understand this answer (as opposed to the scary LaTeX3 syntax...).

Comment: Some update: the above code doesn't work with `\usepackage{amsmath}`, which rise the error `Package amsmath Error: Old form \pmatrix should be \begin{pmatrix}.`. One has simply to use `\begin{pmatrix}\matrL\end{pmatrix}` instead of `\pmatrix{\matrL}` in your code. But then there is an issue with babel french option! I asked about it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586677

Answer (score 12):

The argument is first split at commas in a sequence which is mapped taking into account the positions, so we can add `&` or `\\` as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matr}{m}
 {
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__watson_matr_seq { #1 }
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__watson_matr_seq \__watson_matr_entry:nn
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__watson_matr_seq

\cs_new:Nn \__watson_matr_entry:nn
 {
  #2 % the entry
  \int_case:nn { #1 } { {1}{&} {2}{\\} {3}{&} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\matr{a,b,c,d}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can we generalize it? Yes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matr}{O{2}m}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__watson_matr_size_int { #1 }
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \watson_matr:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__watson_matr_seq
\int_new:N \l__watson_matr_size_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \watson_matr:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__watson_matr_seq { #2 }
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__watson_matr_seq \__watson_matr_entry:nn
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__watson_matr_entry:nn
 {
  #2 % the entry
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { \l__watson_matr_size_int } = 0 }
   { \\ }
   { & }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\matr{a,b,c,d}\ne\matr[3]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're willing to accept a slightly different syntax, with semicolons for ending rows, you can easily produce matrices with different shapes and delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matr}{O{p}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__watson_matr_full_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \begin{#1matrix}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__watson_matr_full_seq \__watson_matr_makerow:n
  \end{#1matrix}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__watson_matr_full_seq
\seq_new:N \l__watson_matr_row_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__watson_matr_makerow:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__watson_matr_row_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__watson_matr_row_seq { & }
  \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\matr{a,b;c,d}\ne\matr[b]{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I think one should include `\usepackage{xparse}`. Even with it, it does not compile with the TexLive2018 distribution... The log file says "! Undefined control sequence. \matr code ...eq {#1}\seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__watson_matr_seq \__wat... l.26 \matr{a,b,c,d}"

Comment: @Watson Only if you're running an older LaTeX kernel. Update, TL 2018 is really outdated.

Comment: @Watson I added a different method for matrices of arbitrary shape.

Answer (score 7):

Here I use `tokcycle` to replace the commas with `&` separators.  WHile I show 2x2 and 3x3, any number of columns are acceptible, as long as the matrices contain 2 or (optionally) 3 rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tokcycle}
\newcommand\matr[1][2]{\tctestifnum{3=#1}{\matrTHREE}{\matrTWO}}
\newcommand\matrTWO[2]{%
  \tokcyclexpress{#1\\#2}%
  \begin{pmatrix}\the\cytoks\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand\matrTHREE[3]{%
  \tokcyclexpress{#1\\#2\\#3}%
  \begin{pmatrix}\the\cytoks\end{pmatrix}}
\Characterdirective{\tctestifx{,#1}{\addcytoks{&}}{\addcytoks{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\matr{a, b}{c, d}
\]
\[
\matr[3]{a, b,c}{d, e, f}{g, h, i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OPTIONAL SINGLE ARGUMENT APPROACH**

This allows any combination of rows and columns within a single argument with the syntax `\matr{ a, b / c, d}` Here, commas are taken a column separators and `/` tokens are taken as row separators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tokcycle}
\newcommand\matr[1]{\tokcyclexpress{#1}%
  \begin{pmatrix}\the\cytoks\end{pmatrix}}
\Characterdirective{\tctestifx{,#1}{\addcytoks{&}}{%
  \tctestifx{/#1}{\addcytoks{\\}}{\addcytoks{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\matr{a, b / c, d}
\]
\[
\matr{a, b,c / d, e, f/ g, h, i}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution without any packages that is based on two fast loops to replace `,` with `&` and `;` with `\\` (so the syntax is the same as in [@wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584979/117050), but the execution is marginally faster, and it has no problems with braced groups, e.g., `\matr{\mathbf{stuff},b;c,d}` works as intended). To change to other parsing tokens than `,` and `;` just swap out these two in every definition...

Also, I separated the parsing macro from the `pmatrix`, so that you could also use other matrix/tabular like enviroments (e.g., `\begin{tabular}{cc}\matrinp{a,b;c,d}\end{tabular}` would work as well).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\matr[1]
  {%
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \matrinp{#1}%
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
\newcommand\matrinp[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter
      {%
        \romannumeral
        \matr@commas
          \matr@nil#1\matr@mark
          \matr@stop\matr@commas
          ,\matr@stop\matr@commas@done
      }%
  }
\long\def\matr@commas#1,#2\matr@stop#3{#3#1&#2\matr@stop#3}
\long\def\matr@commas@done#1\matr@stop#2\matr@commas@done
  {\matr@semicolon#1\matr@stop\matr@semicolon;\matr@stop\matr@done}
\long\def\matr@semicolon#1;#2\matr@stop#3{#3#1\\#2\matr@stop#3}
\long\def\matr@done#1\matr@mark#2\matr@done{\expandafter\z@\@gobble#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \matr{a,b;c,d}\ne\matr{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the party, but for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Regarding input syntax, I make the assumption that `,` is used as the separator between cells in a given row, while `;` is used as the separator between rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro

\luaexec{
    function matr ( s ) 
       s = s:gsub ( ";" , "\\\\" )
       s = s:gsub ( "," , "&" )
       tex.sprint ( "\\begin{pmatrix}" .. s .. "\\end{pmatrix}" )
    end
}
\newcommand\matr[1]{\directlua{ matr ( "#1" ) }}

\begin{document}
$\matr{ a, b ; c, d  }$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Emacs user, such a command already exists. You just type (for example)

```
\[ [[a b][c d]]\]
```

and when the point is on this formula, call the Calc-embedded command (C-x * e) . Emacs immediately returns:

```
\[ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\]
```

As a bonus, Calc allows you to perform many matrix operations.

You have to call again Calc-embedded to return to normal latex-mode.